# I am using the def in Python for the first time and I think I messed up somewhere

Tags: python

I was trying to learn to use def for first time and this error came

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hp\PycharmProjects\whack a mole\main.py", line 36, in <module>
    mole_spawn(600, 440)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

There are multiple answers to solve this question and I saw many answers but I couldn't understand what to do.

Code (only the part of code I think is needed)

```
def mole_spawn(molepos1, molpos2):
    molepos1 = molepos1 + 67
    molpos2 = molpos2 - 3
mole_spawn = random.randint(1, 9)
mole_spawn2 = random.randint(1, 9)
molepos1 = 0
molepos2 = 0
while mole_spawn == mole_spawn2:
    mole_spawn = random.randint(1, 9)
    mole_spawn2 = random.randint(1, 9)
if mole_spawn == 1:
    mole_spawn(100, 440)
elif mole_spawn == 2:
    mole_spawn(350, 440)
elif mole_spawn == 3:
    mole_spawn(600, 440)
elif mole_spawn == 4:
    mole_spawn(100, 260)
elif mole_spawn == 5:
    mole_spawn(350, 260)
elif mole_spawn == 6:
    mole_spawn(600, 260)
elif mole_spawn == 7:
    mole_spawn(100, 80)
elif mole_spawn == 8:
    mole_spawn(350, 80)
elif mole_spawn == 9:
    mole_spawn(600, 80)
mole_rect = mole.get_rect(center=(molepos1, molepos2))
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: if mole_spawn is a number (int), how can you call it  (mole_spawn(100, 440)) ? in this line mole_spawn = random.randint(1, 9) you overwrite your function name. you have to change this line.

Comment: oh now i understand thx mr. or mrs.

Comment: Even if you don't overwrite your function name, the function itself won't work the way that you intend. The function as written does nothing. It creates a couple of local variables but returns nothing, so the values that you assign the local variables are lost.

Comment: sorry i am 3 days in learning python and i am a noob

Comment: any way to fix that?

Comment: You should return values from your functions and assign them to some other variables. All variables inside your function are local (they exist only inside of function). Where do you learn about functions in python? This information should be there.

Comment: i learnt from a book and i think it was expecting me to know that alredy

Comment: oh the book showed me how to make the local variables global variables and i completely ignored it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def mole_spawn(molepos1, molpos2):
    molepos1 = molepos1 + 67
    molpos2 = molpos2 - 3
mole_spawn = random.randint(1, 9)
```

This is your code. Here you define variable `mole_spawn` which shadows and replaces function name `mole_spawn` . So when you call this function later you actually try to call this int variable, which is not possible, thus error.

Answer (score 0):

"def" keyword is used to define a function in python. You used same name for function and variable (mole_spawn) which is causing error.
I suggest you to modify

```
mole_spawn = random.randint(1, 9)
# to 
mole_spawn1 = random.randint(1, 9)

while mole_spawn == mole_spawn2:
# to
while mole_spawn1 == mole_spawn2:
```

and finally modify mole_spawn to mole_spawn1 in every if else statement.

This should work fine.